# @font-face not working in ie8 - the revenge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-8

Yes, I know there is an identical question and many similar ones asked and answered here and many resources online discussing this issue. None have helped in my case so I am taking desperate measures.

I am trying to load web fonts using the @font-face syntax. Here's the code (I am loading more than one but the syntax is identical):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('../typography/MyFont-Book.eot');
    src: local('?'), 
            url('../typography/MyFont-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../typography/MyFont-Book.woff') format('woff'), 
            url('../typography/MyFont-Book.ttf') format('truetype'), 
            url('../typography/MyFont-Book.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

As stated in the title, it's not working in ie8 (works fine in ie9 and 10 and obviously all other browsers). I have tried several things.

In the beginning, I got the error **"CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error"** and I found [this site](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/blog/ie-7-8-error-with-eot-css3111/). I followed the steps, changed the names of the fonts and regenerated them. Apparently, that must have fixed *something* because I am not getting that error anymore. I also see the fonts being loaded correctly in the network sniffer, all coming back with a clean 200.

I have cleared my cache (several times) but still no dice. The font still doesn't show up on the page. Instead, the fallback "Arial" font is displayed, messing up the layout because it's way bigger than the web font.

Anyone got a clue what the eff might be going on?

Comment: [ie8 partially support this](http://caniuse.com/fontface)

Comment: Not sure how that's helpful. What are you trying to say? Also, in the explanation it states *"Partial support before IE8 refers to only supporting EOT fonts."* Considering that I am including EOT that means it *should* work, right?

Comment: Do you have a page you can link to showing the issue?  The new bullet-proof `@font-face` declaration is different to yours.  Maybe worth a try? http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

I have several projects which load fonts down to IE8. They have an almost identical definition  to the one you have but, without the src : local(?).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('../typography/MyFont-Book.eot');
    src: url('../typography/MyFont-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../typography/MyFont-Book.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../typography/MyFont-Book.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('../typography/MyFont-Book.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```